# nodejs TypeError: this.connect is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

When I start my nodejs application, it can't find a function which is really important: `TypeError: this.connect is not a function
    at C:\Users\Jonas\.AtomProjects\PoliticsBrowserGame\app\database.js:89:12
    at tryToString (fs.js:456:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:443:12)`

This is my database class which I want to exist only once because I want only one connection for the application and not multiple connections.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var fs = require("fs");
var eventEmitter = require("./events.js");

function Database() {
  this.connection;
  this.poolCluster;

  var host;
  var username;
  var password;
  var db;

  var config;
  var clusterConfig = {
    removeNodeErrorCount: 5,
    restoreNodeTimeout: 1000,
    defaultSelector: 'ORDER'
  };

  var poolConfig = {
    acquireTimeout: 10000,
    waitForConnections: false,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    queueLimit: 0
  };

  this.connect = function() {
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: config.mysqlHost,
      user: config.mysqlUsername,
      password: config.mysqlPassword,
      database: config.mysqlDb
    });

    this.connection.connect(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.error("Connection couldn't established at " + config.mysqlHost + " (user: " + config.mysqlUsername + ")"
        + "\nError: " + err);
        return;
      }

      console.log("Connected to mysql server at " + config.mysqlHost + " (user: " + config.mysqlUsername + ")");

      this.poolCluster = mysql.createPoolCluster(clusterConfig);

      this.poolCluster.add("APP", poolConfig);
      this.poolCluster.add("ACCOUNTS", poolConfig);
      this.poolCluster.add("GAME", poolConfig);

      console.log("Created Connection Clusters\n- APP\n- ACCOUNTs \n- GAME");
      eventEmitter.emit("MysqlConnectionReady");
    });
  };

  this.getMainConnection = function() {
    return this.connection;
  };

  this.getAppConnection = function() {
    this.poolCluster.getConnection("APP", 'ORDER', function(err, connection) {
      if(err) throw err;

      return connection;
    });
  };

  this.getAccountsConnection = function() {
    this.poolCluster.getConnection("ACCOUNTS", 'ORDER', function(err, connection) {
      if(err) throw err;

      return connection;
    });
  };

  this.getGameConnection = function() {
    this.poolCluster.getConnection("GAME", 'ORDER', function(err, connection) {
      if(err) throw err;

      return connection;
    });
  };


    fs.readFile(process.cwd() + "/config.json", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
      if(err) throw err;

      config = JSON.parse(data);
      this.connect();
    });
}

module.exports = Database;
```

Fixed, thanks to Ajay and Lennart Hase.

But I have another problem too, in my code I set `module.exports = Database;`
When I want to use Database in another file its undefined. I want to use this in another file and I want to use only instance of that because I want only one connection for the app Im running.

Comment: I suspect your problem is related to `this`...

Comment: Please post a MVCE instead of a code dump

Comment: @baao what is a MVCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `this.connect`, in the `readFile` callback `this` won't stands for you db instance. So we need to store `this` reference in some variable like `var self = this`

```
//filename is database.js
function Database() {
   ....
   ....
   var self = this;
   fs.readFile(process.cwd() + "/config.json", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
     if(err) throw err;
     config = JSON.parse(data);
     self.connect();
   });
   ....
}
module.exports = Database;
```

**Update:** Accessing this Database Module from outside.

```
var dbModule = require("./database.js");
var database = new dbModule();
// Give some time to read config.json and connect
database.getMainConnection();
```

Comment: I have another question, when I want to use this class in another code, then the Database class is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're calling `this` within another method, try replacing the last part of your code with the following;

```
var self = this;
fs.readFile(process.cwd() + "/config.json", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;

    config = JSON.parse(data);
    self.connect();
});
```

`this` has a new definition within the callback method of the `fs.readFile()` method, hence you're trying to call a connect method within the callback method which obviously doesn't exist. You're actually trying to call the parent method, this would be a way to achieve this.